# Fill In One Data Frame With Another

Tags: r, tidyr

```
set.seed(1)
data=data.frame("id"=1:10,
                  "score"=NA)
data1=data.frame("id"=c(1:3,5,7,9,10),
                 "score"=sample(50:100,7))
WANT=data.frame("id"=1:10,
                "score"=c(83,81,53,NA,59,NA,58,NA,99,67))
```

I have complete data frame "data" but I do not have values for everybody which is in my second data frame "data1". However for administrative reasons I must use the full data. Basically "WANT" maintains the structure of "data" but fills in the values where they are available.

Comment: `data$score <- data1$score[match(data$id, data1$id)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution.

```
set.seed(1)
data=data.frame("id"=1:10,
                "score"=NA)
data1=data.frame("id"=c(1:3,5,7,9,10),
                 "score"=sample(50:100,7))
WANT=data.frame("id"=1:10,
                "score"=c(83,81,53,NA,59,NA,58,NA,99,67))

library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  select(-score) %>% 
  left_join(data1)
```

I may be reaching but maybe you need.

```
set.seed(1)
data=data.frame("id"=1:10,
                "score"=sample(50:100,10))
data1=data.frame("id"=c(1:3,5,7,9,10),
                 "score"=sample(50:100,7))
WANT=data.frame("id"=1:10,
                "score"=c(83,81,53,NA,59,NA,58,NA,99,67))

library(tidyverse)

  data %>%
  mutate(score1 = score) %>% 
  select(-score) %>% 
  left_join(data1) %>% 
  mutate(score = if_else(is.na(score),
                        score1,
                        score)) %>% 
  select(-score1)
```